# How would I find the closest valid date to one given as an invalid date string?

Tags: vb.net, parsing, validation, datetime

This issue stems from an accounting package that spits out text-based reports with rows of data having invalid dates, like February 31<sup>st</sup> or September 31<sup>st</sup>.

The reports are formatted with spaces and mono-spaced fonts. My goal is to parse out the data needed and generate a more formal report (SSRS).

What I am interested in fixing is the situation where a date is invalid and can't be directly converted into a `DateTime` struct. The date format from the report is `MMM-dd-yy` (e.g.  `Feb-30-10`). **I would like to convert the invalid date strings into the closest valid `DateTime` in the same month** before showing them in the formal report. I've seen this done two ways in my time as a developer, both very poorly, so I want to come up with a simple way of doing it (if there isn't a built-in way I don't know about).

The first bad method I've seen(I can't believe I'm even showing you!):

```
Dim month As Integer = <Parse out the month from the bad date string>
Dim day As Integer = <Parse out the day from the bad date string>
Dim year As Integer = <Parse out the year from the bad date string>

Dim validDate As DateTime

While True
    Try
        validDate = New DateTime(year, month, day)
        Exit While
    Catch ex As ArgumentOutOfRangeException
        day -= 1
    End Try
End While
```

I hope I don't have to explain what I don't like about that method.

The second bad method:

```
Dim badDateString As String = <Current date string from text report>
Dim validDate As DateTime

If DateTime.TryParseExact(badDateString, "MMM-dd-yy", Nothing, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, validDate) Then
    Return validDate
End If

badDateString = badDateString.Replace("31", "30")

' ... try the parse again, if still not valid, replace "30" with "29"
' ... try the parse again, if still not valid, replace "29" with "28"
```

These make for some sad code and me a sad developer.

I've been trying to think of a more efficient way of doing this. Any ideas?

**EDIT**:

I found a solution and have posted it, but I liked Guffa's answer more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reading the previous code, the last code is pretty much what I was going to suggest.

Here is a variation of the code:

```
Return New DateTime(year, month, Math.Min(day, DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here was the solution I discovered before Guffa answered. It takes the parts of a date (month, day, year), uses the number of days in that particular month/year combination to validate the incoming day part, and adjusts if necessary before constructing a new `DateTime`.

```
Dim validDate As DateTime
Dim dayMax As Integer = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month)
Dim newDay = day

If day > dayMax OrElse day < 1 Then
    newDay = dayMax
End If

validDate = new DateTime(year, month, newDay)

Return validDate
```